# Atollic cmd assembly not properly configured

Tags: assembly, cmd, arm

I am trying to assemble a file using this command for my ARM processor in CMD:

```
as -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb example1.s -o example1.o
```

But it is not recognizing the first option: -mcpu

I think it has something to do with the fact when I type: `as --version`
The last line says:

```
This assembler was configured for a target of 'mingw32'
```

It is supposed to say:

```
This assembler was configured for a target of 'arm-none-eabi'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: This smells a lot like any old "two executables with the same name" PATH ordering problem.

Comment: I figured it out, it was sort of what you said. The assignment pointed to the wrong exe...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full command for the assembler should be
`arm-none-eabi-as`. Just `as` will invoke the *host* assembler, and you seem to be on a windows box. Try running `arm-none-eabi-as --version`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out already. But you were right, my assignment pointed to the wrong exec. But thanks anyway!